# how to pluck objects based on ids using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array that has a bunch of ids

```
var arr = ["562f464a9cdf7e6e33aa2514","562f464a9cdf7e6e33aa2514"];
```

and I have an array of objects that looks somewhat like this

```
[{
    "boatId": "562f464a9cdf7e6e33aa2514",
        "canPoll": true,
}, {
    "boatId": "562f4647e6e33aa2514",
        "canPoll": true,
}]
```

I want to pluck out the objects from the second list whose ids are not in the array **arr**

I came up with the following line but it returns false;

```
var finalBoats = _.map(boats, function (boat) {
    if (originalBoats.length > 0) {
        _.each(originalBoats, function (originalBoat) {
            if (originalBoat === boat.boatId) {
                return boat;
            }
        });
    } else {
        return boat;
    }
});
```

I also have to account for times that the first array might be empty.

Not sure how I can do this in underscore.

Update : Here is what I want to do exactly

```
var arr = ["1","2"];

   var unfilteredBoats = [{
        "boatId": "3",
            "canPoll": true,
    }, {
        "boatId": "2",
            "canPoll": true,
    }]
```

so the extracted array of elements should be

```
[{
        "boatId": "3",
            "canPoll": true,
    }]
```

also if arr is empty, it shouldn't filter at all, that part is rather simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in VanillaJS

```
var filteredArr = originalBoats.filter(function(e) {
    return arr.indexOf(e.boatId) === -1;
});
```

Same can be done using underscore's [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains)

```
var filteredArr = _.filter(originalBoats, function(el) {
    return _.contains(arr, el.boatId) === false;
});
```

---

Demo

```js
var arr = ["1", "2"];

var unfilteredBoats = [{
  "boatId": "3",
  "canPoll": true,
}, {
  "boatId": "2",
  "canPoll": true,
}];

var filteredArr = unfilteredBoats.filter(function(e) {
  return arr.indexOf(e.boatId) === -1;
});

console.log(filteredArr);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to extract the elements from the arr array that are not present in originalBoats

Comment: @Bazinga777 Can you please add an example of both the arrays, I think the above should work.

Comment: @Bazinga777 I've added demo, please check

Comment: You are a life saver. That worked well. Didn't know about the filter property. Thanks